# Как настроит свое сообщение для неправильного ввода в поле?

Tags: php, yii2

### Использую формы yii2 для получения данных от пользователя!

Нужно для каждого поля ввода формы, сделать собственный вывод об не правильно введенных данных.

Класс модели  выглядит так:

```
<?php


namespace app\models;


use yii\base\Model;

class MyForms extends Model{

    public $name;
    public $email ;

    public function rules() {
        return [
           [['name' , 'email'], 'required', 'message' => 'имя не введено'],
            [['name' , 'email'], 'trim'],
            ['email', 'email', 'message'=> 'введите адрес']

        ];
    }

   public function attributeLabels(){
        return [

            'name' => 'Ваше ім’я',
            'email' => 'Електронна пошта',

        ];
    }

    public function getErrors($attribute = null)
    {
        return [
            'name' => ['не введенное имя'],
            'email' => ['не правильный адрес'],

        ];
    }


}
```

*Но почему то отображается сообщение переданное для name! И `getErrors`я так понял за это тоже не отвечает!*

*Прошу помощи новичку в yii ))*

***Как это правильно реализовать ?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понял, то вам нужно для каждого атрибута вывести своё сообщение о том, что он не заполнен (если он не заполнен). В этом случае можно сделать так:

```
public function rules() {


    return [

        [['attribute1'], 'required', 'message' => 'Введите атрибут 1'],

        [['attribute2'], 'required', 'message' => 'Введите атрибут 2'],

    ];


}
```